# What to do with ExptIntf and ToolIntf and TIExpert?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-5, delphi-6

As is routine when trying to move components to newer versions of Delphi, [Borland breaks compatibility by renaming, hiding, or removing various classes used by design time code](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/26107).

Today's case involves a code library that we purchased years ago, which we have the source code for. Attempting to install the "design time" package in Delphi 7 IDE fails when the unit **`ExptIntf`** is not found:

```
uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, Dialogs,
  Contoso3Const, StdCtrls, ExtCtrls, ContosoRpt, DBTables, ContosoDataWz, ContosoExtra,
  ExptIntf,
  ToolIntf, ContosoWizard, ActiveX;
```

No problem. We'll comment out the reference. But then another unit, **`ToolIntf`** is not found:

```
uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, Dialogs,
  Contoso3Const, StdCtrls, ExtCtrls, ContosoRpt, DBTables, ContosoDataWz, ContosoExtra,
  //ExptIntf,
  ToolIntf, 
  ContosoWizard, ActiveX;
```

No problem. We'll comment out the reference. This is when the real fun begins.

The class **`TIExpert`** isn't found:

```
{$INCLUDE compilers.inc}

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, Dialogs,
  Contoso3Const, StdCtrls, ExtCtrls, ContosoRpt, DBTables, ContosoDataWz, ContosoExtra,
  {$IFDEF DELPHI_6_UP}
  //They've been removed in D6
  //ExptIntf, ToolIntf,
  {$ELSE}
  ExptIntf, ToolIntf,
  {$ENDIF}
  ContosoWizard, ActiveX;

type
  TContosoIDEWizard = class(TIExpert)
  public
     ...
```

A quick Googling says that [the code will never work in Delphi 6](http://www.delphigroups.info/2/dc/299037.html):

> That is the old style OTA that was depreciated in D4 and gone in D6.  You will 
>   have to re write using the OTA interface style introduced in D4.

The poster doesn't mention what the new OTA interface style introduced in D4 is.

Given that i'm going to have to re-write two classes in 3rd party code:

```
  TContosoIDEWizard = class(TIExpert)
  public
    SourceBuffer: PChar;
    function GetName: string; override;
    function GetComment: string; override;
    function GetGlyph: HICON; override;
    function GetStyle: TExpertStyle; override;
    function GetState: TExpertState; override;
    function GetIDString: string; override;
    function GetAuthor: string; override;
    function GetPage: string; override;
    procedure Execute; override;
    function CreateForm(Report : TCustomContosoRep; const FormIdent : string; VarList : TStrings) : TMemoryStream;
    function CreateSource(const UnitIdent, FormIdent: string; VarList : TStrings): TMemoryStream;
  end;

  TNewContosoReport = class(TIExpert)
    function GetName: string; override;
    function GetComment: string; override;
    function GetGlyph: HICON; override;
    function GetStyle: TExpertStyle; override;
    function GetState: TExpertState; override;
    function GetIDString: string; override;
    function GetAuthor: string; override;
    function GetPage: string; override;
    function GetMenuText: string; override;
    procedure Execute; override;
  end;
```

what do re-write them into? i assume it is as simple as using a different base class name, that contains all the same methods, and no actual code re-writes (of code i didn't write) will be required.

**Note**: The identity of the 3rd party library has been poorly obfuscated for your safety

**Note**:

- Tagged `delphi-5`; as that's the IDE i'm moving from
- Tagged `delphi-7`; as that's the IDE i'm moving to
- Tagged `delphi-6`; as that's the IDE that broke functioning code
- Tagged `delphi` as that's the development tool we're talking about

Comment: This is **very** old API and was considered obsolete at the time of D7 for sure. Newer old code `uses ToolsAPI`.

Comment: "Routine lack of backward compatibility"? This happened once (when Unicode was added with D2009). The changes you're mentioning  weren't "routine", and were announced two versions in advance (D4->D6) and documented. Borland hasn't been involved with Delphi for years. If you're going to complain, at least complain about factual matters. :-) (It's not really meaningful, though, when your complaint is about upgrading from a ~Y2K product to a ~2002 product, which is still more than a decade old. I'm sure people migrating from 16-bit Win 3.1 to Win 95 today are dealing with major issues, too.) :-D

Comment: @Ian I can't believe that you are finally leaving Delphi 5 and moving into modern times. Oh, wait .....   ;-)

Comment: @KenWhite You must have forgotten the `DsgnIntf` dcu being removed. Later `DsgnIntf` was renamed to `DesignIntf`. Later `DesignIntf` was removed.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Don't get too excited over an upgrade to [Delphi 7 Second Edition](http://thepiratebay.se/torrent/7347097/DELPHI_7_SECOND_EDITION_v7.2). i acquired a copy of XE2, which is when i remembered that D7 was the last Delphi IDE that had a Delphi IDE.

Comment: There have been lots of changes in OTA. But then the IDE has changed too. Why should Emba maintain compat for older IDEs in OTA. Certainly for OTA they are welcome to change things around in my view. In fact I wish they'd break compat more than they do. So they can break free from the past.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'm all for them breaking whatever they want. But [it's more pressure to not upgrade](http://www.reddit.com/r/delphi/comments/1srntm/reasons_to_ditch_your_old_delphi_version_and_move/). i've downloaded an fan-released copy of Delphi 7, and i'm looking at doing a major code-base rewrite to support D7 (e.g. Variants, Types, DsgnIntf, DesignIntf, DesignInterface, TThread fundamental changes). All on my own time. Maybe by doing this i can sucker people into paying tens of thousands for the privilege of pain.

Comment: Basically the pain is worse 'cos you left it to long and stored up the debt. We stayed with D6 for ages. Moving to Unicode Delphi two years ago was a challenge. Would have been easier to move progressively. That said, the Unicode change is really the only tough upgrade.

Comment: @Ian: All of that was documented (don't have the help still installed, or the readme that mentioned it in the release notes), but it prompted Steven Trefethen to write a blog post called "Whatever happened to 'Proxies.pas'?" to explain the issue when the breaking change happened *two versions after the upcoming change was announced* that clearly stated "Future versions will break things, so make your changes now" (paraphrased, of course). You can probably find it in wayback or something; I don't have a link to it any longer.

Comment: @Ken, it was Jeff Overcash, and the article survived the transition from Borland to Embarcadero: http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/27717.

Comment: "i've downloaded an fan-released copy of Delphi 7"

Uh... this seems to indicate that your copy of Delphi 7 isn't a properly licensed version. For a commercial product, anything "fan-released" is likely a serious breach of license.

Comment: @AllenBauer i doubt the person who created and release *Delphi 7 Second Edition* agreed to any license; they probably acquired a copy of Delphi 7 outside of commercial channels.

Comment: @Rob: Ah, thanks for the correction. Memory fails sometimes. :-) Steve was the one who did the articles on actions in the early days.

Comment: @Ian, that goes without saying... however your usage of it also constitutes a violation of the license. Since Embarcadero holds the Copy*Right*, they are the ones who controls how the copies are distributed. I know that many folks don't see it this way, but the fact of the matter is that there are many folks whose livelihood depend on that product. I believe that purchasers of the latest version of Delphi are entitled to past versions, most likely back to at least Delphi 2007, which would be a better version to move to than D7.

Comment: @IanBoyd  -- admitting to using a pirate publicly on StackOverflow is a bold move.  I'd recommend that no one help you.

Comment: @NickHodges [It's a bold strategy](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Ru8DMW-grY). Lets see if it pays off for me.

Comment: I guess you should submit your complaints and moans to the person who supports and develops D7SE. You've just lost all my respect.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Because the answer is different if i were using an owned copy of [Delphi 7 Personal Edition](http://i.imgur.com/jk6NUSs.jpg)? This is where people confuse the question with the example.

Comment: Because we form personal relationships with people. Up until today I had lots of respect for you. You are intelligent, write excellent questions, and sometimes good answers. But I don't want to help you any more. I have no respect for you as a person. My choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TIExpert` was replaced with a new hierarchy of interfaces derived from `IOTAWizard`.  There are plenty of OpenTools API tutorials online, such as [this one](http://www.tempest-sw.com/opentools/wizards.html), as well as [official documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Extending_the_IDE_Index).

Comment: Sadly the official documentation sucks.

Comment: Did you actually read the documentation I linked to? It is quite thorough, which yes, cannot be said about many other areas of the documentation.  But the OTA documentation covers a lot of information and samples.

Comment: Hmm. The page you linked to is fine. But OTA is atrociously documented. Most methods are "Embarcadero Technologies currently has no more info" boiler plate.

Comment: Since i don't know what i want, it makes it hard to decide what scenario i'm looking to do. i'm staring at a Borland class that has an `Execute` method; which scenario is that. Perhaps if there was some documentation explaining the **why** the api is the way it is, the **how** would be obvious. (E.g. COM cannot be learned from reading the documentation, only from reading [Essential COM](http://books.google.ca/books/about/Essential_COM.html?id=kfRWvKSePmAC&redir_esc=y)). As it is now, i'm as stuck as the guy from 2004, "It doesn't work and you need to use this".

Comment: @IanBoyd: it would help if you explained what your `TIExpert` wizard does. The behavior of it's `Execute()` method is dependent on the value it's `GetStyle()` method returns. Then someone can explain which OTA interface(s) to implement as a replacement.

Comment: It's [not actually my code](http://www.quickreport.co.uk/). Based on my quick skim of the wizards, one is a *New Thing* option icon under the **New** menu.